# Guardar datos en la Base de datos

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Conexion

```html
public SqlConnection con_Sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xx\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Bd; user ID=oriente; password= 8522 ; Integrated Security = True");
       
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["rut"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script> window.open('../Vistas/Index.aspx','_parent') </script>");
                }

            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Insertar

```html
string insert = "INSERT INTO registro_jurisprudencia(rut_user, ruc, n_ingreso, rit, delito, fiscalia, fiscal, fecha_ingreso, extr_or_ordi, juzgado, recurso, recurrente, Causales_Nulidad, fecha_fallo, sala, resultado, url_ficha_caso)" +
                                                    "VALUES " +
                                                    "('" + rut + "','" + txtRuc.Text + "'," + txtNIngreso.Text + ",'" + txtRit.Text + "','" + txtDelito.Text + "','" + txtFiscalia.Text + "','" + txtFiscal.Text + "','" + lblFecha_Hoy.Text + "','" + selOrdinaria.Text + "','" + selJuzgado.Text + "','" + selRecurso.Text + "','" + selRecurrente.Text + "','" + txtExclusivoORNulidad.Text + "','" + txtFecha.Text + "'," + selSala.Text + ",'" + selResultado.Text + "','" + url.Text + "')";
                                    Clases.Guardar_Jurisprudencia ingresar = new Clases.Guardar_Jurisprudencia();
                                    if (ingresar.Guardar_jurisprudencia(insert))
                                    {
                                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mensaje", "<script>swal ( 'Registro Exitoso' , 'Datos han sido registrados exitosamente' )</script>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mensaje", "<script>swal ( 'Registro Fallido' , 'Datos no han sido registrados' )</script>");
                                    }
```

tengo una aplicación que guarda datos en sql, mi pregunta es ¿por que se guardan los datos de forma local solamente, pero cuando lo subo a un servidor y lo usa persona desde otro pc este no guarda los datos, pero si funcionan los select puede consultar? a que se debe esto. Soy nuevo en el tema y es el primer sistema.

Comment: Y seria muy importante ver tu codigo por ejemplo, o saber como armaste tu cadena de conexion. O algo que nos pueda ayudar a ayudarte...

Comment: Quiero creer que esos datos no son reales no?

Comment: y la base de datos es siempre la misma? o tenes otra base de datos en un servidor?

Comment: son datos de mi codigo, excepto las credenciales

Comment: este sistema trabaja solo con esa BD, pero en el servidor existen otros programas que utilizan sus respectivas BD

Comment: no se entiende cual es el problema. Definitivamente si no hay error, en alguna base esta haciendo el insert...

Comment: lo que pasa que cuando abro el sistema desde la url y desde el computador donde esta la bd  me inserta los datos. Pero cuando lo abro desde otro pc, este solo accede a los select y los insert no los realiza

Comment: y tira un error? la base de datos esta con tu back?

Comment: lo lee pero no lo inserta, no la BD está en sql server  en el computador donde realice mi proyecto

Comment: con todo lo que decis no puedo ayudarte... no deberia ser distinto sin importar la pc desde donde te conectes a la pagina (que no esta en tu pc no?) la base de datos deberia estar en un servidor (no en tu pc)... hay algo raro en lo que decis, o lo estas explicando mal. A ver, explica bien donde esta cada parte de tu sistema. y fijate que el usuario tenga permisos de insert...